Creating a data asset in Azure but getting this Error
I'm trying to create a ML data asset and I'm following this link: https://microsoftlearning.github.io/mslearn-ai-fundamentals/Instructions/Labs/01-machine-learning.html
to get it done but I am constantly getting this error

I know my files are not the exact ones in the examples but even when I use those files I'm getting the same error.So I'm not sure what the problem is since this my first time using ML in Azure.

When the dataset type is MLTable, you also need to give the MLTable file defining the files to be included and there transformations.
Next, .xlsx is not supported.
Refer here for supported files in MLTable.
Below is the sample file you should be having.
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/MLTable.schema.json 

paths:
    - pattern: ./*.csv

transformations:
  - read_delimited:
      delimiter: ","
      header: all_files_same_headers
      encoding: utf8

Or
you can directly give the filename.
paths: 
  - file: ./titanic.csv
transformations: 
  - read_delimited: 
      delimiter: ',' 
      encoding: 'ascii' 
      empty_as_string: false
      header: from_first_file

So, in your case the MLTable file is
paths: 
  - file: ./CarPrice_Assignment.csv
transformations: 
  - read_delimited: 
      delimiter: ','

The folder should contain files like below.

And in mltable file you add the content according to your files.
Refer more about working with mltable files here.
